# ESD Wrist Strap When Working on Monitors and Power Supply

Tags: esd, computers

My book for the A+ exam specifically says not to use ESD for repairing monitors or power supplies.

Why is this? I understand that their capacitors hold lethal amounts of charges, but the motherboard also has capacitors.

Comment: What does "A+ exam" mean? Doesn't your course material say why - if it says so we don't know the reason why it says so. I'd say not using ESD can lead to static discharges and then the monitor or power supply can get damaged by ESD.

Comment: `not to use ESD for repairing monitors` - I totally agree - any use of ESD is bound to lead to component damage at some point. Sloppy use of words can make any sentence mean exactly the opposite of what is intended. Sloppiness in engineering is something to be highly avoided. Attention to detail is highly recommended.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question, this is an actual safety issue. When working with high voltages (>48V), ESD straps can be dangerous.

Comment: @Justme [CompTIA A+](https://www.comptia.org/certifications/a): "CompTIA A+ is the industry standard for establishing a career in IT."

Comment: @LiorBilia given that a proper ESD wristband must be used with a 1 Mohm cord, it seems unlikely that 48 volts is going to cause a safety problem here. Of course, if some person decides to use any old bit of cord to connect their wristband to earth then it's survival of the fittest I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The motherboard voltage does not exceed 12V. While AC powered units could be 30x higher minimum and 3000x higher for CRT's.

Therefore the 1Mohm leakage currents are large sources of stored energy and not the same as the static discharge being depleted for CMOS safety.

https://economicforall.com/library/lecture/read/239975-when-should-you-not-wear-an-esd-strap

Comment: Assuming the OP meant "ESD-Protection", it still does not make any sense. For CRTs with Voltages up to 40kV there could theoretically a point be made because 40mA would be considered dangerous. But the HV-Supply of a CRT can't deliver 40mA and the stored charges are pretty low. An a power supply it makes even less sense.

Comment: @kruemi unless the high voltage PFC cap and Flyback doubler caps are discharged safely, you should not touch them with a grounded ESD strap when live or still charged.  This one supplies 40 mA at 14kV https://www.allanson.com/wp-content/uploads/AHVPS-714-40-MV-High-Voltage-Power-Supply-Spec-Manual-v5.pdf   ... for those who repair HV http://www.electronicrepairguide.com/high-voltage-circuit.html

Comment: @Tony-Stewart-EE54 unless the high voltage PFC cap and Flyback doubler caps are discharged savely you should **not touch them at all**! An ESD-Strap won't change anything in this situation because in most cases the Strap is not the only way to Earth.
I never stated that there are no 40kV/40mA supplies, they are just not in CRTs.

Comment: OK so are you suggesting 1M wrist clip is safe ?  I did not suggest touching them at all.  Usually you put one hand in your pocket to work on CRT's which reduces capacitance to ground and increases resistance. to Gohm, but more important is redirects current away from heart